# multiplication of two finite number give infinity

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, binary

Given two numbers $x$ and $y$, which $x,y\leq1$, I can express them in binary number $x=0.a_{1}a_{2}...$, $y=0.b_{1}b_{2}...$. Now I proceed in this way:

The new number $xy=c_{0}+0.c_{1}c_{2}...$, where:

$c_{0}=0+h_{0}$

$c_{1}=0+h_{1}$

$c_{2}=a_{1}b_{1}+h_{2}$

$c_{3}=a_{1}b_{2}+a_{2}b_{1}+h_{3}$

$\vdots$

Where $h_{i}$ is the carrying obtained from $i+1$ equation, with the expression $\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{j+k=i+1}a_{j}b_{k}+h_{i+1})\rfloor$

Now the problem arise, if I let all $a_{i}=b_{i}=1$ and try to calculate the $h_{1}$ starting from $h_{i}$ ,say $i=10000$, the $h_{1}$ is huge. In fact I can calculate the limit when $i$ tends to infinity, which is infinite. That means $xy$ is unbounded but $xy=1$ in this case($0.1111...=1$). So what is the problem here? I clearly make some simple mistake but I cannot spotted it.

**Edit**: Answer to the comment. If we truncated the $x,y$ to n-order, that is, $x=0.a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n}$, $y=0.b_{1}b_{2}...b_{n}$. Then we have the following result:

$c_{n}=a_{1}b_{n-1}+...a_{n-1}b_{n}+h_{n}$

$c_{n+1}=a_{1}b_{n}+...a_{n}b_{1}+h_{n+1}$

$\vdots$

$c_{2n-1}=a_{n-1}b_{n}+a_{n}b_{n-1}+h_{2n-1}$

$c_{2n}=a_{n}b_{n}$

While we can see that the formula is correct. The sequence $h^{(m)}_{n}$ itself converge, but the limit when $m$ goes to infinity does not for $n=m+1,m+2...$. It may be possible to take the limit of $h^{(m)}_{n}$ to the sequence $h_{n}$. But intuitively it is weird that there are infinite carrying inside but disappear at $c_{0}$. Also why we can take $h_{2n-1}=1$(and $h_{2n}=0$) in this case?

Comment: My guess is that you are not attenuating the carrying amount.  $h_i$ comes from taking $c_{i+1}$ and dividing out the factor of $2$ (rounding down) that comes from shifting by one digit position.  A number like $10000$ will not survive thousands of divide-by-2 operations and remain large.  If you fail to divide by 2 ever, then yes it will grow quite quickly with $i$.

Comment: If you look at some smaller cases, I believe that you’ll find that in general the square of $0.\underbrace{11\ldots11}_n$ is $0.\underbrace{11\ldots11}_{n-1}\underbrace{00\ldots00}_n1$, and the carries, from right to left, are: $$0,1,2,\ldots,n-1,n-1,n-2,\ldots,2,1$$

Comment: @Erick Wong I have already included the factor of 2 in the expression of $h_{i}$. But as you can see, if I start with $h_{10000}$, there will be $9999 +h_{10001}$. Even I let $h_{10001}=0$, the $h_{9999}=(9998+4997)/2>10000$, the expression is still unbounded

Comment: @Ken.Wong Thanks for pointing out that it was in the formula, I missed that.  However, why do you say that $(9998+4997)/2 > 10000$?  Perhaps you can see why I speculated there was a missing halving operation :)

Comment: @Brain M. Scott So if $n$ is infinity, there will be infinite carrying in some $i$, then finite carrying occur finally?

Comment: I believe that what you tried to write is $$h_i = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\left(h_{i+1}+\sum_{j+k=i+1}a_jb_k\right)\right\rfloor.$$ Of course, this still tells that, if any such sequence $(h_n)$ exists, then $h_n\to\infty$ will diverge as $n\to\infty$ for some infinite binary expansions such as $x=y=0.111\dots_{(2)}$. However, I doubt that $(h_n)$ is well-defined for such cases, as the above recurrence relation works only in backward direction (i.e., $h_{n}$ can only unambiguously determine $h_{n-1}$ and not $h_n$). So it is not surprising that $(h_n)$ is not well-defined in some circumstances.

Comment: Or perhaps we may possibly define $(h_n)_{n\geq0}$ as the limit of $(h^{(m)}_n)$'s as $m\to\infty$, where each $(h^{(m)}_n)$ is the sequence of carries arising in the multiplication of truncations $0.a_1\dots a_m$ and $0.b_1\dots b_m$. Given the monotonicity of carries as functions of digits, I believe that this limit is indeed well-defined. Then this will produce the correct multiplication formula even if $(h_n)$ itself may possibly diverge as $n\to\infty$.